# I am having problems installing gdal in python anaconda 3.8.5 64bit

Tags: installation, anaconda, gdal

i am trying to install gdal through anaconda prompt with  `conda install gdal`
but its showing `failed with initial frozen solve retrying with flexible solve`
then  `filed with current.repodata.json` will try new source
then the whole process repeating and then it's showing to try different channel
and when I'm trying to install by pip it's showing error in visual studio c++ 14 or higher required even if I have the version already installed.
Please help I am new in this.

Comment: You could try mamba. In your root environment install `conda install -c conda-forge mamba` and then `mamba install gdal`.

Comment: I have installed mamba. But when I'm trying mamba install gdal. There is an error; its showing Encountered problems while solving. Problem: package mamba-0.7.10-py38hdd88130_0 requires libarchive >=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed